# Is it possible to find and extract two substrings with a single regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, capture

Spent half a day reading up on SO and elsewhere.

Say I have a string:

`"a_b_c_d_e_f_g_1_2_3_4_5"`

Is there a single regex that can construct a result based on two matches? E.g. construct a string which is a concatenation of two matches: First one - between 3rd and 5th and the second one between 8th and 10th underscores (regardless of how many other characters are between them)?

The result for the above sample would be:

`"d_e_2_3"`

Thanks!

Comment: Use capture groups to match the substrings you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is it possible to find and extract two substrings with a single regex?*

No it is not, but one can use a combination of a regular expression that [captures groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#capturing-groups-in-replacement) and [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Syntax).

The regex for the OP's use case might look like this ...

[`(/^(?:[^_]*_){3}([^_]+_[^_]+)_(?:[^_]+_){3}([^_]+_[^_]+).*/)`](https://regex101.com/r/goH1zc/1)

... and can be read as follows ...

0. One wants to start searching from the very beginning of a String ... `^`.
1. Next one wants to find any character sequence that is NOT `_` ... `[^_]`.

- but since it might not always be assured that a string starts not with `_`, one is looking it up optionally ... thus it turns into `[^_]*`.
- of course such a sequence should be followed by a `_`, thus the former term turns into `[^_]*_`.
- since this pattern is supposed to repeat itself 3 times (`{3}`) it needs to be grouped (`(...)`) but it should not be captured (`?:`) ... thus the partial expression turn into `^(?:[^_]*_){3}` and would already match `'a_b_c_'` from the OP's example of `'a_b_c_d_e_f_g_1_2_3_4_5'`.

2. Now one wants to match a non-`_` character sequence, followed by an `_`, followed by a non-`_` character sequence, followed by an `_`. One wants to capture everything except for the last `_`. Thus the 2nd part of the regex looks like this ... `([^_]+_[^_]+)_`.
3. The third part is similar to the first one except that one is sure about the existence of the next character (sequence) which is not an `_`. Thus the 3rd part of the regex looks like this ... `(?:[^_]+_){3}`.
4. The 4th part is an exact copy of the 2nd one ... `([^_]+_[^_]+)`.
5. In order to match the string entirely, one goes for the rest of the string via a greedy wild cart ... `.` matches anything ... `*` in case there was still something to match.
6. Since one also might support multiline matches, one has to provide both flags the global (`g`) and the multiline (`m`) one.

Example code ...

```js
const regX = (/^(?:[^_]*_){3}([^_]+_[^_]+)_(?:[^_]+_){3}([^_]+_[^_]+).*/gm);


console.log(
  'a_b_c_d_e_f_g_1_2_3_4_5'.replace(regX, '$1_$2')
);
console.log(
  '_b_c_d_e_f_g_1_2_3_4_5'.replace(regX, '$1_$2')
);
console.log(
  'b_c_d_e_f_g_1_2_3_4_5'.replace(regX, '$1_$2')
);
console.log(
  '_c_d_e_f_g_1_2_3_4_5'.replace(regX, '$1_$2')
);


console.log([...
`a_b_c_d_e_f_g_1_2_3_4_5
_b_c_dd_ee_f_g_1_222_333_4_5
b_c_dd_ee_f_g_1_222_333_4_5
_c_dd_ee_ff_g_1_222_333_444_5
c_dd_ee_ff_g_1_222_333_444_55_66
_dd_ee_ff_gg_1_222_333_444_55_66`
.matchAll(regX)].map(([match, $1, $2]) => ($1 + '_' + $2))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Peter, thank you so much for taking time time to explain.